# What is the worst case complexity for the following program

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

```
function Do-something(a,b)
   if b = 0 then
      return 1
   else if b is even then
      x <- Do-something(a,b/2)
      return x * x
   else if b is odd then
      x <- Do-something(a,(b-1)/2)
      return x * x * a
   end if
end function
```

This is a recursive function that will eventually return $a^b$ Each time it starts again B is halved (if it is odd is essentially halved and rounded down from the -1). So I believe it gets sent through recursion $\left\lfloor log_2(b)+2 \right\rfloor$ times. So in big-O notation would it be something like O($\left\lfloor log_2(b)+2 \right\rfloor$) or is my thinking off base?

Comment: Shouldn't the runtime be a function of the inputs $a$ and $b$? What is $n$ here?

Comment: Trace the execution when $b = 8$ and then when $b = 16$.

Comment: This is a tricky problem to examine the runtime of, because the size of x grows so large it has to be taken into account.  Those multiplications become really expensive.  If you are a beginner at this kind of thing, this isn't a good problem to learn on.

Comment: @Taladris you're correct, that was my fault.

Comment: @EthanBolker I see. I updated my answer using this advice

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this algorithm for calculating powers runs in time $O(\log b)$.

There is no need to add the $+2$ or to specify the base of the logarithm or use the floor since the big-$O$ behavior is the same.

@Danielv notes correctly that for integer arithmetic the multiplication time may be significant. This algorithm is a standard one for modular arithmetic, where that is not the governing bottleneck.